# Create large amounts of motion blur using small filters

Tags: filter-design, motion

As part of an image preprocessing step, I need to generate vertical and horizontal motion blur with a filter that's 30 pixels long:

```py
def motion_blur(image, filter_length):
    horizontal_kernel = np.ones((filter_length, 1)) / filter_length

    # create blurred images
    blurred_vertical = cv2.filter2D(image, ddepth=-1, kernel=horizontal_kernel)
    blurred_horizontal = cv2.filter2D(image, ddepth=-1, kernel=horizontal_kernel.T) # T for transpose
    return blurred_vertical, blurred_horizontal
```

but I am implementing this algorithm in a compute shader, where I *think* I only have access to the neighboring 7 pixels in either direction.

More specifically, I need to set `filter_length` to 30 but the largest filter length I can use is 15.

Should have kept my DSP book :(. This is possible, right?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on exactly what you mean by **blur**.

If I take a length 15 boxcar kernel, apply that to a signal twice, then the effect is like a triangular kernel. If I apply that triangular kernel to the boxcar, then the effect is like a parabolic curve.

The code

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.ones(15)/15

y = np.convolve(x,x)

z = np.convolve(x,y)

plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(y,'r')
plt.plot(z,'g')
```

illustrates this:

[image: Illustration of boxcar, triangular, and parabolic curves.]

Comment: You're right that it depends on what is meant by "blur". I think the only way to get the response from a length 30 rectangular filter if only a length 15 filter is possible is to downsample the image by a factor of two, filter, and then upsample. Definitely not perfect though.

Comment: @whlteXbread If you filter with a length 15 filter twice, you'll get the effect of a length 29 filter (15 + 15 - 1).

Comment: but as you demonstrate in the plot above, the result of (i * boxcar_15) * boxcar_15 will be significantly different than the desired result: i * boxcard_30

Comment: @whlteXbread sure, if you want something different, use a different starting blur.